# how to display multiple images in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am developing simple social media using laravel 7,and i want to give my users capability of uploading multiple images to the database,
The codes work fine but i don't know how to display each image to my blade view

This is my controller Logic

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{

    $data = request()->validate([
        'question' =>'required|max:255|unique:photos',
        'details' => 'nullable',
        'link' => 'nullable|url',
        'photos[]' => ['nullable' , 'image'],
      ]);



      if ($request->hasFile('photos')) {

        foreach($request->file('photos') as $file){

            //get filename with extension
            $filenamewithextension = $file->getClientOriginalName();

            //get filename without extension
            $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            //get file extension
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            //filename to store
            $filenametostore = $filename.'_'.uniqid().'.'.$extension;

            Storage::put('public/photoss/'. $filenametostore, fopen($file, 'r+'));
            Storage::put('public/photoss/thumbnail/'. $filenametostore, fopen($file, 'r+'));

            //Resize image here
            $thumbnailpath = public_path('storage/photoss/thumbnail/'.$filenametostore);
            $img = Image::make($thumbnailpath)->resize(1000, 1000, function($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            $img->save($thumbnailpath);
        }
      }





      auth()->user()->photos()->create([
        'question' => $data['question'],
        'details' => $data['details'],
        'link' => $data['link'],
      'key' => mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999),
     'slug' => Str::of($data['question'])->slug('+'),

        'photos'  => $thumbnailpath,
      ]);





      return redirect('/')->with('status' , 'Posted Successful');


}
```

The above codes store images in public/storage/photos/thumbnail folder

So i need to display each image in my view

I have tried this but images do not show up

```
            @foreach($posts as $post)
       <div class="card m-5">
           <div class="flex m-1">
           <a href="/{{$post->user->username}}/">
           <img src="{{$post->user->userprofile->profilePicture()}}" class="w-10 rounded-circle pl-2 border-primary" alt="">

               </a>
               <span class="text-sm pl-1 mt-1 font-bold">{{$post->user->username}}</span>
               <span class="text-xs  text-muted mt-2 uppercase offset-3">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->created_at)->diffForhumans() }}
            </span>
           </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="font-bold text-xl m-2">{{$post->question}}</div>
            <a href="/{{$post->user->username}}/{{$post->slug}}/">
                <img src="/storage/photoss/thumbnail/{{$post->photos}}" class="w-100" alt="">

               </a>
               <div class="container">

               </div>



            </div>
       </div>
       @endforeach
```

Comment: What happens instead? Why do you use direct links to images instead of the usual `asset` helpers?

Comment: You're associating **one** photo with the current User but then looping through `$post->photos` I feel like there's a missing step here like how are posts associated with photos?

Comment: @apokryfos
My model is photo,which belong to user 
$post is  just a variable